# Knockout mapping add issue

Tags: knockout.js

I have a method where I am trying to add a child to my parent, but when the call is made to the method, the context of the calling parent is undefined.

The code (abbreviated for clarity) Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/poundingCode/THghy/

```
// Initialized the namespace
var my = {};
    my.models = {};

    // View model declaration
    my.vm = (function (model) {
        var memberVm = {
            id: ko.observable(model.Id),
            company: ko.observable(model.Company),
            fName: ko.observable(model.FName),
            lName: ko.observable(model.LName),
            name: ko.observable(model.Name),
            positions: ko.observableArray([]),
            totalPositions: ko.observable(),
            totalProjects: ko.observable()
        };

        // children
        memberVm.loadPositions = function (positions) {
            memberVm.totalPositions = 0;
            memberVm.totalProjects = 0;
            $.each(positions, function (i, p) {
                memberVm.positions.push( new my.models.Position()
                .company(p.Company)
                .companyId(p.CompanyId)
                 .description(p.Description)
                .id(p.Id)
                .memberId(p.MemberId)
                .name(p.Name)
                .title(p.Title)
                .projects(p.Projects) 
                );
                memberVm.totalPositions++;
                memberVm.totalProjects += p.Projects.length;
            });// end for each
        }; //end load positions

        memberVm.loadPositions(model.Positions);

        memberVm.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.fName() + ' ' + this.lName();
        }, memberVm);


        // Computed observable function.
        // We append it to the ViewModel here.

        // return object
        var vm = {
            id: memberVm.id,
            company: memberVm.company,
            fName: memberVm.fName,
            fullName: memberVm.fullName,
            lName: memberVm.lName,
            name: memberVm.name,
            positions: memberVm.positions,
            totalPositions: memberVm.totalPositions,
            totalProjects: memberVm.totalProjects,    

        };
        return vm;
    });

    /////////////////////////////////////
    // Add a position - or at least try to! this is where I get into trouble.

    my.vm.addPosition = (function () {
        var pos = new my.models.Position();
        pos.memberId = my.vm.id;
        my.vm.positions.push(pos);
    });
    /////////////////////////////////////
    // TypeError: my.vm.positions is undefined my.vm.positions.push(pos);
    my.models.Member = (function () {
            id = ko.observable();
            company = ko.observable(); 
            fName = ko.observable();
            lName = ko.observable();
            name = ko.observable();
            positions = ko.observableArray([]);

    });
    my.models.Position = (function () {
        this.company = ko.observable();          
        this.id = ko.observable();           
        this.memberId = ko.observable();
        this.name = ko.observable();
        this.title = ko.observable();
        // place holders
        this.totalProjects = ko.observableArray();
        this.totalCredits = ko.observableArray();
    });


 var viewModel = my.vm(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
my.setUI();
```

The HTML

```
      <script type="text/html" id="positionItemTemplate">
          <div class="summary" data-bind="attr : {onClick: 'my.showDetails(' + id() + ')', href: '#detail_'+ id()}">
                                    <a data-bind="attr : { href: '#detail_'+ id()}">
                                    <h2><label data-bind="text: company().Name"></label>: <label data-bind="text: title"></label></h2> </a>
                                    <h3><label data-bind="text: title" ></label> <label data-bind="text: startDate" ></label> - <label data-bind="value: endDate" ></label></h3>

                                </div>
                                <div data-bind="attr : {id: 'detail_' + id() }" class="details" style="right: 580px;">
                                  <div class="positionOverview">
                                   <h2><label data-bind="text: company().Name"></label>: <label data-bind="text: title"></label></h2> </a>
                                     <a data-bind="attr : {href: '#detail_'+ id()}">   <div class="editor-label"><label>Position</label></div></a>
                                        <div class="editor-field">
                                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: company().Name" class="textbox-long">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="editor-label">
                                            <label>Title</label>
                                        </div>
                                      <div class="editor-field">
                                          <input type="text" data-bind="value: title" class="textbox-long">
                                      </div>
                                        <div class="editor-label">
                                            <label>Summary</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="editor-field">
                                           <textarea data-bind="value: summary"  rows="4" cols="60"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="editor-label"><label>Compensation</label></div>
                                        <div class="editor-field">
                                            <select data-bind="options: $parent.compensations, value: compensationId, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="editor-label"><label for="HoursPerWeek" class="hourly">Hours/Week</label></div>
                                        <div class="editor-field">
                                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: hoursPerWeek" class="number-short">
                                        </div>
                                      <div class="div-table">
                                          <div class="div-table-row">
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><label for="StartDate">Start Date</label></div>
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><label for="EndDate">End Date</label></div>
                                              <div class="div-table-col"></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="div-table-row">
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" data-bind="value: startDate" class="date"></div>
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" data-bind="value: endDate" class="date"></div>

                                          </div>
                                          <div class="div-table-row salary">
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><label for="SalaryStart">$/Hr Start</label></div>
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><label for="SalaryStart">$/Hr End</label></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="div-table-row salary">
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" data-bind="value: salaryStart" class="date"></div>
                                              <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" data-bind="value: salaryEnd" class="date"></div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <input id="btnAddProject" type="button" value="Add Project" data-bind="attr : {onClick: 'addProject(new project())'}">
                                        <input type="button" data-bind="attr : {onClick: 'my.showDetails(' + id() + ')'}" value="Update"/>
                                    </div>                                                                   
                                </div>
      </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="marquee center">
                <aside class="aside">
                    <div class="display">
                     <label data-bind="text: 'Total Positions: ' + totalPositions" ></label><input value="Add Position" type="button" data-bind="attr : {onClick: 'my.vm.addPosition()'}"/><br />

                    </div>
                    <div class="adPanel">
                        <h4><div id="message"></div></h4>
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <section id="primary" class="primary">
                <article id="article1">
                    <section >
                        <div id="positions">
                            <div class="position" data-bind="template: { name: 'positionItemTemplate', foreach: positions, as: 'position' }">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </article>
<!--            <footer class="footer">
                <p>Copyright © 2008 All Rights</p>
            </footer>-->
        </section>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your fiddle seems different than the code that you pasted.  Where is it that you are seeing a problem?

Comment: I don't know what happened to the fiddle, I'll repost soon. The problem is that the call to my.vm.positions throws an error that positions is null.

Comment: Updated the fiddle, thanks in advance to all those who take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that your `my.vm` is a constructor function that you can use to create an instance of a `my.vm`.  However, the `addPosition` function was added directly to `my.vm` and tries to push to `my.vm.positions`.

Ideally what you want to do is make the function available on an instance of your vm and push to that instance's `positions` array.

So, you would put `addPosition` inside your vm declaration and have it operate on the `vm` variable that you are returning.  At that point your bindings run into issues when you add a new position, as `company` is empty and some of the bindings refer to `company().Name`

Comment: Very astute of you to notice, yes I'm trying to add children which would be able to draw multiple properties from the parent record. I've been following John Papa's Knockout examples and the 'revealing model' pattern, moving my function call inside the VM as you suggest, but now the VM doesn't bind to the page. the fun never ends.